# Why don't the pills in Bootstrap 4 have any style?

Tags: css, menu, bootstrap-4

I was trying to make a vertical navbar with Bootstrap 4 pills, but when I tried to use them, I couldn't get the style to show. They all look like regular links.

**Pills without styles:**
[image: Pills without style]

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>home" class="nav-link">Admin Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>user-list/1" class="nav-link">Users</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>category-list/1" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>car-list/1" class="nav-link">Cars</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<?php echo MAIN_URL;?>" class="nav-link">Main Page</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the active Link gets the styling

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>home" class="nav-link active">Admin Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>user-list/1" class="nav-link">Users</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>category-list/1" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>car-list/1" class="nav-link">Cars</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="<?php echo MAIN_URL;?>" class="nav-link">Main Page</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

That means only the element that contains the active class has the styling (for example the first entry in my answer code)

[More Info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#pills)

Comment: Thank you, I was sure I'd made a rookie mistake somewhere. Glad to know where